# Publishing "baked" Orchard CMS to Azure CloudService

Tags: azure, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am using Orchard CMS 1.6 with target deploy it to Azure cloud service. I have followed the steps in documentation Deploying Orchard to Windows Azure(http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Deploying-Orchard-to-Windows-Azure)

however,it hit time out error again and again during cooking receipe (Have tried with small VM)

My idea, is instead of running the setup process during initial setup, I would like to deploy the "baked" ready copy of Orchard (and manually deploying the DB scripts to SQL Azure) to cloudservice.

I tried with working on　Orchard.Azure.sln and building the package again with ClickToBuildAzurePackage.cmd but now I come to the error

"The type 'Orchard.Environment.Configuration.AzureBlobTenantManager' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly"."

Any idea or experience to share?

Thanks.

Comment: I was working with Orchard 1.5 deployment to Azure. I did not have much issues with Orchard build. However, I noticed that Orchard as a Azure Cloud service version was much slower (response time was taking 2 to 3 times longer) than Orchard as a Azure Website. Unfortunately did not have much time to investigate that problem.

Comment: I found out one way in discussion (http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/393252)

Which repoint the database connection string in blob

Comment: Hi Tom, I have had faced the exact performance issue problem in cloudservice, however I noticed I were using different region for cloudservie, azure database and storage.And once putting all in the same region in azure and did some warmup page setting, the response time improved by at least 60%

Comment: many thanks for sharing your experience. I will definitely try again with Orchard 1.6 as a cloud service and will make sure that all services are located in the same datacentre.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I made it works on cloudservice.

My idea is to cooking the recipe on my local machine instead of on Azure itself, to avoid timeout problem. So, we will have the ready cooked structure  in Azure Storage and database schema.

Then, build the package with ClickToBuildAzurePackage.cmd and deploy the package to Azure Cloud Service. The instance shall skip the setup process since the Azure Storage contains the required information.

Below are my workarounds:

1. Download [Orchard.Source.1.6.zip](http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/view/90325) from the Orchard Codeplex
2. Extract and open the Orchard.Source.1.6\src\Orchard.Azure\Orchard.Azure.sln
3. Open the solution and edit your Orchard.Azure.Web role, change the Data Connection setting and Diagnostics to your production/development storage account.
4. Create an empty database in your SQL Azure (Assume you are using SQL Server)
5. Hit F5 to kick start the application and enter the setup information to start cooking recipe.
6. You may have the Orchard cooking in browser.
7. Once the Orchard is cooked. Check your Azure storage(With CloudBerry for example), you shall have the following folders:
    media
    site
    wad-control-container
    wad-iis-logfiles
8. Follow the instruction from [Deploying Orchard to Windows Azure](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Deploying-Orchard-to-Windows-Azure)
9. You shall have the instance of Orchard running without kicking the setup process